# ASP.NET Identity: How to handle broken connection string to database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I'm developing a web-based mvc application with asp.net identity. The problem is that when the user sign-in successfully, there is a chance that the connection with database get broken or become unaccessible. My question is that how can I handle unexpected errors for ASP.NET Identity? Since it executes some methods from internal calls, I can't define any try/catch block for them. How can I handle these situations to make user to sign-out and let them sign-in again? Take a look at the following stack trace that occurred to my application.

```
SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot open database "DatabaseName" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'My-PC\MyName'.]
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +414
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +78
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +196
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +146
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +16
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +94
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +110
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) +424
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<<ExecuteAsync>b__3>d__6.MoveNext() +226
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<ExecuteAsyncImplementation>d__9`1.MoveNext() +354
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.<OpenAsync>d__8.MoveNext() +636

[EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open.]
   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.<OpenAsync>d__8.MoveNext() +716
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.<EnsureConnectionAsync>d__9.MoveNext() +487
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.<ExecuteInTransactionAsync>d__3d`1.MoveNext() +306
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<ExecuteAsyncImplementation>d__9`1.MoveNext() +363
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.<GetResultsAsync>d__e.MoveNext() +622
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.<FirstMoveNextAsync>d__0.MoveNext() +250
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.<FirstOrDefaultAsync>d__25`1.MoveNext() +388
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.<<OnValidateIdentity>b__1>d__4.MoveNext() +785
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
   Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.<AuthenticateCoreAsync>d__0.MoveNext() +1430
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
   Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.<BaseInitializeAsync>d__0.MoveNext() +595
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
   Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext() +264
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext() +413
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext() +413
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.<RunApp>d__5.MoveNext() +191
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.<DoFinalWork>d__2.MoveNext() +189
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.StageAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult ar) +69
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.EndFinalWork(IAsyncResult ar) +64
   System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +415
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle global errors in Global.asax file, and redirect the user to a generic error page, for example, with some description of the problem and a link to try again.

By the way, if you provide the right credentials in connection string this won't happen ;-)

Comment: Actually it is not about providing right or wrong credentials, the matter is that I have several databases and one might get deactivated. I need to handle this and to force user to signout and sign-in again. The problem with "Global.asax" exception handling is that it doesn't allow me to access HttpContextBase to call HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut();

Comment: Sounds like your real problem is your database. It's not the user's responsibility to sign out and sign in again because you can't keep your infrastructure running properly.

Comment: Looool, OMG! Lets say I want to handle a situation that database is down, but user already authenticated. I want to handle any database connection error. What should I do in this case?

Comment: @Sayid Use a fail over partner or a cluster, for example.

Comment: @Saeid You can access the current Httpcontext instance through the  Current property of HttpContext class.

Comment: Thanks @Oscar, I fixed this issue long time ago. Actually I should check the database existence before I call Identity functions.